# UIwebview verticall scrolling not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I add webview and navigationbar inside my view controller .
Web view is display properly but when I am start to drag scroll vertically that webview and stop dragging, uiwebview reach in top.
In short, Scrolling is not working in vertically.
here is my code.

`- (void)viewDidLoad`
{

```
[super viewDidLoad];


web.delegate=self;
NSBundle *myAppBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSString *htmlFilePath = [myAppBundle pathForResource:@"infotext" ofType:@"htm"];


[web loadHTMLString:htmlFilePath baseURL:nil];



[self.view addSubview:web];
```

}

Here I take webview inside IB and set it outlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you have `webview.userInteraction = NO` which disables the scrolling in the webView or you have added the webview to the wrong view as a subview.

Try First adding this above your addSubview : `web.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

If that doesn't work then you need to look at which viewController all this code is from. In order for this to work since you are using a UINavigationController, you need to make sure this code is happening in the RootViewController and the NavigationController as well as the RootViewController are wired up correctly.

It sounds like you just drug over a Navigation Bar from IB which won't really do what you are hoping for in this case so its probably likely that its causing your issues.